# Cannot run Excel Add-In from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vsto, ms-office, office-addins, excel-addins

I have Visual Studio 2019 16.8.2 and I have installed the Office Development tools from Visual Studio Installer. I then created an Excel Web Add-In project and when I try to run the project, I get this error:

[image]

In the output window, there isn't much useful info:
[image]

Excel is of course installed, I have the following version:
[image]

Could there be some form of Compatibility issue? or maybe something in the Visual Studio Version?
I tried to check online but couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should not Visual Studio as administrator. When running as Admin it results in the error. Running as not admin works correctly.